# API Consuming library - How to structure a composer package

Tags: php, composer-php

One simple service offers an API to use some of its features. I want to create a composer package which will consume the following API and I want it to be compatible with other PHP projects. I read about the topic and came up with the idea to to use `GuzzleHttp` to make the requests (I saw it in few other libraries). However I'm confused about the structure of an API consuming library. (It's a REST API).

The API gives access to two resources: `Customers` and `Products`.

`Products` resource has the following methods:

- List all available products - **GET**
- Add products - **POST**
- Delete product - **DELETE**

`Customers` resources has the same methods.

What I've done so far is the following structure (*I'm following psr-4 as suggested*):

```
src/ 
--MyName/
----PackageName/
------Resources/
------Containers/
------Exceptions/
------Client.php
```

`src/MyName/PackageName` is the structure I read in a tutorial about creating a composer package. `MyName\PackageName` will be my namespace throught it.

File `Client.php` is a class which loads some configuration about authorization (Basic Auth) and creates new instance of `GuzzleHttp\Client`. Also I have two methods for building a request (setting HTTP Method, URL & additional parameters).
Also I have a `__call()` method which instantiates new object from Folder `Resources` and the first element of the array passed as second argument is the method which should be called.

Folder `Resources` contains two files `Products.php` and `Customers.php` which are classes for handling all methods for those two resources I mentioned above. Every class extends `Client.php`.

Folder `Containers` contains files for processing the response data from every resource.

Folder `Exceptions` contains classes for custom exceptions which might be thrown in the process.

Is that a good approach to a easily maintainable library or I'm missing some of the concepts here?

Comment: Your question is huge. I'm tempted to write an entire essay for every single paragraph you wrote, because there's so much room for improvement and plenty of not ideal stuff you plan. However, most would only be my opinion - and that makes it unsuitable for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Sven, can you give me some guidance where to start from? Or can we discuss it somewhere where it's suitable for this kind of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to structure a composer package

To cut a long story short: stick to PSR-4, decide for a folder layout and expose this layout in the autoloading section of your composer.json file. The rest is: pick clear and understandable class and method names to expose the API.

---

Your question is a mix of different things and some things overlap each other.

When talking about the structure of your project, we have to split between source (object-oriented design) and the folder layout (autoloading relevant) and the composer integration (with autoloading description).

Let's go through this in order...

**a) source-code**

> However I'm confused about the structure of an API consuming library.
>   Is that a good approach to a easily maintainable library or I'm missing some of the concepts here?

The questions is: Is my code clear and precise enough (for myself and for others, e.g. to be consumed in another project)?

The advises to give here are:

- Picking clear class and method names makes use easier, like `Company\PhotoApi\Client.php`

  Namespace and Class could probably expose the vendor, e.g person or company producing the source and then you could include the API name, finally the classname.
- Follow some basic OO principles
- How you fetch the data from the API is taste based. Going with Guzzle is ok, while going with a lighter solutions, like `file_get_contents` or `curl`, would probably work out, too. It depends.
- in regard to maintainability:

  - The lower the number of files and the less complex your code is, the better the maintainability. Do you need an Exceptions folder? How many files are there? Why not simply stick to PHP's default exceptions?
  - You might also consider, that your lib has to change if the API changes, right? And, then if your lib changes, all the code in projects using your lib has to change, right? If there is only a small set of endpoints exposed by the API, then it might be better to use just one object and provide accessor methods for them, instead of using multiple objects as accessors, which might be too fine-grained. This means that projects using your API will (possibly) have fewer lines changes when upgrading. Anyway: your users will tell you, if your API lib is too difficult to use.

While you have something like:

```
       $PhotoApiProducts = new Company\PhotoApi\Products;
       $products = $PhotoApiProducts->get();
```

This is also possible:

```
       $api = new Company\PhotoApi\Client;
       $products = $api->getProducts();
       $consumers = $api->getConsumers();
```

**b) folder structure**

> I'm following psr-4 as suggested

In regard to the folder layout, my suggestion is to stick with PSR-4.
But you have to decide the exact folder layout yourself. You might take a look at the examples section of the PSR-4 standard to see different folder layouts respecting PSR-4. http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

**c) Composer integration**

And then finally.. you add a `composer.json` file describing your project.
The autoloading section is the most important part, because this is were you expose the structure of your project to Composer.

When you have decided to use PSR-4 for your project, then simply say so in the autoloading section and add the mapping from your namespace to source, like

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Foo\\Bar\\": "src/Foo/Bar/"
        }
    }
```

Now, a user of your Composer project has to load the composer autoloader during the bootstrap and then he might start using your lib, by just using a namespaced classname from it - then the autoloader will do its work.